# Connecting different machines with common file system via UDS sockets

Tags: c, sockets, unix, server, client

I am trying to connect 2 EC2 instances using UDS sockets and share some data between the 2. Now, it is known that UDS sockets cannot be used to establish a connection between 2 different machines(https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/422300) since they use the local filesystem

However, I have a common EFS mounted on both the instances, so they essentially share the same EFS file system, where the socket is created. But the connection is being refused nevertheless.

What could be the reason for the same, and is there any way that I can enable this form of communication where I can use the common file system to run communication sockets

Answer (score 2):

UNIX domain sockets share data between different sockets endpoints running within the same instance of an operating system. The "file" in the file system is just the identifier so that to sockets on the same system can find each other. The data exchange itself is not done using the file system but using structures within the OS kernel.

This means that it is not enough to have a shared file system between different OS instances to share data with UNIX domain sockets. Both socket endpoints have to be within the same OS instance.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! So is there some other mode of communication that can work utilising the shared file system, but simultaneously also allow communication between 2 separate hosts?

Comment: @Cyborg: As I said, the purpose of the shared file system in UDS is only to have a common identifier, not for the data transfer itself. If you want to achieve a similar thing but between multiple hosts you could for example create a TCP listener in one host, write the listeners IP:port (and maybe some authentication information) into a shared file and wait for the other host to work as TCP client.